# How to factor and simplify algebraic expressions with fractional or negative exponents

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Im trying to factor:

$(x+3)^{1/2}-(x+3)^{3/2}$

The answer is $-(x+3)^{1/2}(x+2)$

Could someone explain how I would factor the expression?

My answer is

$(x+3)^{1/2}[1-(x+3)]$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$(1-(x+3)) = (1-x-3) = (-x-2) = -(x+2)$

Now isolate the negative sign and you get the answer.

Comment: So then, would $(x^2+4)^{3/2}+(x^2+4)^{7/2}$ factor to $(x^2+4)^{3/2}(x^4+16)$?

Comment: No. $(x^2+4)^{3/2} + (x^2+4)^{7/2} = (x^2+4)^{3/2}\left[1+(x^2+4)^2\right] \ne (x^2+4)^{3/2}(x^4+16)$